# Work with xml file and Wordpress

Tags: xml

by a URL that generate an XML page, example: http://thegamesdb.net/api/GetGame.php?id=2
how can import it in Wordpress site with mapped request custom field?
thanks
Stew

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: [`simplexml_load_file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php) + [`wp_insert_post()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post)

You want to feed on the XML, and parse it for information that you can use to make posts. Here is a short example, because I am not going to dissect that particular feed for you:

```
$feed = simple_xml_load('http://example.com/feed.xml');

if($feed){
    foreach($feed['items'] as $item){
        $post_args = array(
          'post_title'    => $item->title,
          'post_content'  => $item->body,
          'post_status'   => 'publish',
          'post_author'   => 1, // this should represent you, or an author you want these to belong to
          'post_category' => array(8,39) // optional
        );
        $post_id = wp_insert_post($post_args);
        if($post_id){
            // add  meta values if you want
            $post_meta_values = array(
                'meta_key_slug_1'    => $item->some_information->,
                'meta_key_slug_2'    => $item->some_more_information,
            );

            // add meta
            foreach($post_meta_values as $key => $value) {
                update_post_meta($post_id, $key, $value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I would start by bringing in the xml file and then doing a `print_r()` of it so you can learn its structure.

Comment: i need add it the loop?

Comment: No. This would be something you'd run as often as you need to sip on posts. Just once? Dunno. Another option to get the main feed object is `fetch_feed()` http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/fetch_feed. Basically, you're going to need to know how to work with XML objects, and use `wp_insert_post()` to actually create them. _Where_ you put this code (could go into a function) and how you alter it, is entirely up to you.

Comment: thanks for your infos but seem to be hard build it, im php newbie, know you a tutorial or plugin for do it?

Comment: Yes. It is hard. But also empowering. No, I don't have a tutorial or anything. Start out small as a proof of concept, and work your way up. Good luck!